# Laravel impossible where query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a filter for some products. I have the majority of it working however I am encountering an error with an impossible `where` clause.

The table contains multiple rows for a single product and I am trying to match multiple criteria per product, which is causing it to fail.

If you have an opinion on this, or possibly a way to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

The database table looks like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------
    |id | FilterKey | filterValue | product_id |
    --------------------------------------------
    |1  | Colour    | Gunmetal    | 1          |
    |2  | Colour    | Silver      | 1          |
    |3  | Size      | 750cc       | 1          |
    |4  | Size      | 1000cc      | 1          |
    |5  | Colour    | Red         | 2          |
    |6  | Colour    | Blue        | 2          |
    |7  | Size      | 750cc       | 2          |
    |8  | Size      | 1000cc      | 2          |
    --------------------------------------------
```

And the filter looks like this:

```
public function scopeFilterProduct($query, $filters)
{
    $this->filters = $filters;
    if (count ($this->filters) === 1 && isset($this->filters[0]))
    {
        return $query;
    }
    $query->join('product_filters', 'products.id', '=', 'product_filters.product_id')->Where(function($query){
        foreach ($this->filters as $filter => $vals)
        {
            $this->filter = $filter;
            $this->vals = $vals;
            $query->Where(function ($query){

                $query->Where('filterKey', $this->filter); 

                $query->Where(function($query){
                    foreach ($this->vals as $val){

                        $query->orWhere('filterValue', $val); 
                    }
                    $this->vals = null;
                });

            });
            $this->filter = null;
        };
    }); 
    return $query;
}
```

This then outputs the following SQL statement:

```
select
  distinct
    `products`.`id`
  , `product_id`
from
 `products`
inner join
 `product_filters`
on
 `products`.`id` = `product_filters`.`product_id`
where 
     (
         (`filterKey` = 'Colour' and (`filterValue` = 'gunmetal'))
       and
         (`filterKey` = 'Size' and (`filterValue` = '750cc'))
     )
     and
       `products`.`deleted_at` is null
```

[image]

If selected, as in the screenshot, then only 'product one' should be present on the page.

Comment: This is called a set division.The logic to follow is "get a product for which there doesn't exist a selected filter that it does not have"

Answer (score 0):

The scope you have added in my opinion is wrong. Even your database structure is incorrect in my opinion. Here is how i would structure this:

## Filters Table

This model will hold all the filter values. For example, `Colour`, `Size` etc. Here is how the filter table will be structured:

```
-----------------
|id | name      |
-----------------
|1  | Colour    |
|2  | Size      |
-----------------
```

So your eloquent model become something like this:

```
class Filter extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'products_filters');          
    } 
}
```

## Products Table

Your product models becomes:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Filter::class, 'products_filters');          
    } 
}
```

## products_filters Table

After the above changes, here is how the table will be structured:

```
--------------------------------------------
|id | filter_id | filterValue | product_id |
--------------------------------------------
|1  | 1         | Gunmetal    | 1          |
|2  | 1         | Silver      | 1          |
|3  | 2         | 750cc       | 1          |
|4  | 2         | 1000cc      | 1          |
|5  | 1         | Red         | 2          |
|6  | 1         | Blue        | 2          |
|7  | 2         | 750cc       | 2          |
|8  | 2         | 1000cc      | 2          |
--------------------------------------------
```

Now you can simply query the filters table, then get associated products for all filters. After that you simply need to compile a list of unique products.

## Unqiue products based on selected filters.

```
$ids = [];
$products = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection();

foreach($filters as $filter) {
    foreach($filter->products as $product) {
        if(!in_array($product->id, $ids)) {
            $ids[] = $product->id;
            $products->push($product);
        }
    }
}

return view('results', compact('products'));
```

In your view, you need to write:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
// Your product block HTML
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Raza, I am looking into implimenting this now. Hopfuly this will solve it. 

To help, how would you consider pulling a product where it matches to exactly 2 of the filters?

Comment: Updated my answer to describe how i would filter unique products based on provided product filters.